# if and else command in android preferences

Tags: android, checkbox, if-statement, android-preferences

I've been trying to add some preferences to my app for a couple of weeks now

I really only need the checkbox feature.

I'm trying to control the visibility of a single radio button with the checking of a checkbox

Here is my Preferences.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.view.View;


public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {

private RadioButton btn01;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
       btn01 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RadioButton01);

       Preference customPref = (Preference) findPreference("customPref");

                      customPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener(){

                          public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                                      "The Custom Preference Has Been Clicked",
                                                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                          SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences(
                                           "myCutomSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = customSharedPreference
                                           .edit();
                          editor.putString("myCustomPref",
                                           "The preference has been clicked");
                          editor.commit();
                          return true;}

                          public void CheckBox() {

                          final CheckBox ThisCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById (R.id.checkboxPref);{   
                          ThisCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

                              public boolean OnCheckedChange (CompoundButton compoundButton) {
                          if (ThisCheckBox.isChecked()){ 

                          {
                          btn01.setVisibility(0);
                          }{

                          btn01.setVisibility(2);

                          }}                                    
}                            


;
});


};}});}}
```

Any way I'm pretty sure this is completely wrong and i get an error on this line

ThisCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

any idea why? I think its to do with the way I've called the line above but whether I use final, boolean or void it still generates errors

this is the error message

The type new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton, boolean)

So I guess what i'm asking is

Am I doing the Preferences Right
And how do I do the If else command properly??

Comment: You should make your variable names start with lowercase. Upper case names are usually used to represent classes.

Comment: sorry can you point them out for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the signature of the method you are trying to override is incorrect. Replace this:

```
public boolean OnCheckedChange (CompoundButton compoundButton) {
```

with this:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
```

**EDIT**
Ok, here's an attempt to fix the whole class.  Backup your current code, then select all the code below, and copy it.  Select all of the code in your class and replace it with this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {

    private RadioButton btn01;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
        btn01 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RadioButton01);
        Preference customPref = (Preference) findPreference("customPref");

        customPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener(){

            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"The Custom Preference Has Been Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("myCutomSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = customSharedPreference.edit();
                editor.putString("myCustomPref","The preference has been clicked");
                editor.commit();
                return true;
            }

            public void CheckBox() {
                final CheckBox ThisCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById (R.id.checkboxPref);
                ThisCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton,boolean test) {
                        if (ThisCheckBox.isChecked()){ 
                            btn01.setVisibility(0);
                        } else {
                            btn01.setVisibility(2);
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
        });
    }
}
```

The above code compiles with no issues for me in eclipse

Comment: Thank You =P a helpful tip but there is still an error on the line i mentioned does anyone have any ideas =/

Comment: its on this line>> ThisCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()  abd the error is>>  The type new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method 
 CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton, boolean)

Comment: It works fine in my IDE.  Did you copy and paste the line I provided or did you edit the code in place?  The three changes are: 1: changed return type from `boolean` to `void`. 2: changed method name from `OnCheckedChange` to `onCheckedChanged` (note the "d") and 3: added the `boolean` parameter.

Comment: No i got all that but the error still appears to stand =/  Highlighted code is specifically the part in the brackets on the mentioned line and i'm completely at a loss now. i've been through checking spelling and syntax over and over but i still get nothing.  I wonder if the eclipse IDE contains its own errors or maybe my file structure for the app is wrong. Do i need to import onCheckedChange as opposed to onCheckedChange?

Comment: If you are using eclipse, then you can hover your mouse over the error and it will give you a little pop-up message.  It should have a link that says `Add unimplemented method` or similar.  Click on that and eclipse should add the correct method for you.

Comment: cool thanks =D but now do i need to call OnCheckedChanged somewhere because its saying its not used locally?

Comment: Sounds like you now have the old (incorrect) method and the new one that eclipse has created.  You can move any of your code from the old one to the new one and just delete the unused old method.

Comment: No sorry thats just reverted it back to how it was with the same error. Just with a new method name.

Comment: What am i doing wrong.  I just copied and pasted your code but for some reason it doesn't like the @Override annotation. I was never sure what that did so i don't have a clue.  I'm sorry I'm sure this isn't your fault i'm just the worlds biggest newb at the moment ='(

Comment: Which of the two `@Override` annotations is giving the error? And what is the error?

Comment: above this line>>  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton,boolean test) {     This error >>  The method onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton, boolean) of type new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){} must override a superclass method

Comment: can you copy all your current code and upload it to pastebin.com (or similar) so we can see the current state

Comment: well, you've got me stumped.  That exact code compiles fine when copied into eclipse.  Perhaps you can create a brand new Android project in eclipse, then create this class in the new project.  If that works then you know you have an issue with the setup of your current project.  Other than that I'm out of ideas.

Comment: just to check. Preferences.java should be in the source folder and not somewhere else

Comment: when you create your android project (eg MyApp) you provide a package name, for example `com.example.myapplication`.  Eclipse will create this folder structure under the src directory, so you will have `src/com/example/myapplication/MyApp.java`.  I would create your Preferences.java in the same package as your main class, ie `src/com/example/myapplication/Preferences.java`

Comment: this website>> mentions a getPrefs() method http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences but i didn't know where this method should have gone maybe it requires this method to work. The article says to put it in the onStart() method but i don't know where to find that =/

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in CheckBoxPreference class and check out this article on setting and using preferences:

http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences

Using your code above, there are several errors in it (apart from those already identified) namely, your if/else statement is missing an 'else' and the curly braces do not appear to match (assuming that pasting the code in hasn't screwed it up) - This appears to compile ok:

```
import android.app.Activity;
```

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.view.View;

public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity
{
    private RadioButton btn01;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
       btn01 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RadioButton01);

       Preference customPref = (Preference) findPreference("customPref");

      customPref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener()
      {
          @Override
          public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object object)
          {
              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "The Custom Preference Has Been Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("myCutomSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor = customSharedPreference.edit();
              editor.putString("myCustomPref", "The preference has been clicked");
              editor.commit();
              return true;
          }
      });
}

  public void CheckBox()
  {

      final CheckBox ThisCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById (R.id.checkboxPref);

      ThisCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
      { 
          //@Override
          public void onCheckedChanged (CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked)
          {
              if (ThisCheckBox.isChecked())
              {
                  btn01.setVisibility(0);           
              }
              else
              {
                 btn01.setVisibility(2);

              }                                    
         }
      });
  }
```

}

Comment: You know i probably should have mentioned this before but that is the tutorial i used to get started =/ sorry.  So instead of using compound button i use CheckBoxPreference is that right?

Comment: Thank You just changed my code and it looked a bit more hopefull but i still get that error on that same line  >The type new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.onPreferenceChange(Preference, Object)

Comment: I don't know how you amended the code but be sure not to mistake onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) vs onPreferenceChange(Preference preference) , they have different meaning

Comment: Check out my edited code above - for some reason the paste has split some of the import statements and the start of the class from the rest of code.

Comment: Hmm thankyou for the code amendments but there is still an error on the line>>  ThisCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() the error message states>>    Any clue? I'm beginning to think this is a problem with eclipse

Comment: also the site you referred me to mentions a GetPrefs method that should be put in the OnStart method.  Sorry for being really dense but where exactly is the OnStart method?? =S

Comment: sorry the error message states >>  The type new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton, boolean)